# Inserting into a particular position in a double linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have made a post here on code review which can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196409/generic-double-linked-list-follow-up). I was told that my insertPosition function does not update head or tail. When I asked how some questions about this claim, my questions fell on deaf ears.

Here is the function:

```
template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::insertPosition(int pos, const T& theData) {
    Node* current = head;
    int i = 0;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (i++ == pos) {
            Node* newNode = new Node;
            newNode->data = theData;
            // Let's do the wiring
            newNode->previous = current->previous;
            newNode->next = current;
            if (newNode->previous != nullptr) {  // If the node is inserted at the end
                newNode->previous->next = newNode;
            }
            current->previous = newNode;
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Does the latter function not update head or tail? If so, how should I change it?

Comment: If `head` is initially `nullptr`, where in your code do you expect it to change to no longer be `nullptr`?

Comment: When I create the node using my createNode function (essentially it is a push_back function or append)

Comment: I think the point is this `insertPosition()` function can not add a new head.

Comment: Does your list actually *have* a `tail` ?

Comment: Yes, it doe shave a tail. I already have a function for insertHead as well.

Comment: You are not using them here though..

Comment: I see your point so should I create some conditional statements where if the user wants to insert at the beginning or end then I call on the insertHead or insertTail functions?

Comment: Do you have a reason to not want `pos == 0` to mean *insert at the head*?

Comment: @jxh I am not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: Do you have a reason that`insertPosition(0, data)` should be different from `insertHead(data)` in all cases, including when `head` is `nullptr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the function not update `head` or `tail`?

No, it does not.  Look at it for yourself.  There is no mention of `head` or `tail` anywhere in its code, and it doesn't call any class methods that might refer to those members, either.

The code should look something like this:

```
template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::insertPosition(int pos, const T& theData)
{
    if (pos < 0)
        throw std::invalid_argument("pos is not a valid index");

    Node *current = head, *previous = nullptr;
    while (pos-- > 0) {
    {
        if (!current)
            throw std::invalid_argument("pos is not a valid index");

        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = theData;

    // Let's do the wiring
    newNode->previous = previous;
    newNode->next = current;

    if (newNode->previous)
        newNode->previous->next = newNode;
    else
        head = newNode;

    if (newNode->next)
        newNode->next->previous = newNode;
    else
        tail = newNode;
}
```

Comment: I understand most of this code but not the if(newNode->previous) I am not sure whats going on there, could you explain?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx The code is checking if the new node is being inserted at the very front and/or very back of the list. If `previous` is pointing at an earlier node, the new node CAN'T be a new `head` node, so `head` is untouched and `previous->next` is updated to point at the new node. Otherwise, the new node MUST be a new `head` node, so `head` is updated to point at the new node.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx Likewise, if `current` is pointing at a later node, the new node CAN'T be a new `tail` node, so `tail` is untouched and `current->previous` is updated to point at the new node. Otherwise, the new node MUST be a new `tail` node, so `tail` is updated to point at the new node.

Comment: I sort of understand what you saying so if(newNode->previous) states "hey newNode, are you point to an earlier node?" If it is then we say okay newNode cannot be a new head so lets update and make previous->next point to the newNode?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx that is correct.  When it comes to understanding linked lists, it helps to draw the nodes on paper and follow the code logic step by step, erasing/drawing links between nodes as the code performs them.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. You seem very advanced and I hope one day to be as good as you, do you have any advice or books I should read?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx see [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).  But I'm a self-taught programmer and haven't read very many programming books (most of my learning is from reading other people's code), so I can't advise which ones are better than others.

Comment: I am on the same boat, I am a mathematician my education but instead of being in theory land I need to learn to code well to get a good job :).